# how to check each input attr if type radio and checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, radio-button

I have a bunch of inputs within the div and I need to select each of them and add name attr's value and value of the element into an array, and for some reason my radio buttons won't pass the value.

So I have html:

```
         <div id="form">
            <!-- Meno -->
            <span class="form_element_title">Meno:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="name" id="" class="form_input_element_text" vtype="vietor"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <!-- Priezvisko -->
            <span class="form_element_title">Priezvisko:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="surname" id="" class="form_input_element_text" vtype="vietor"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <!-- Vek -->
            <span class="form_element_title">Vek:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="age" id="" class="form_input_element_text" vtype="vietor"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <!-- Pohlavie -->
            <span>Pohlavie:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="sex" id="" value="male" class="" vtype="vietor" checked="checked" />
            <span>Muž</span>
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="sex" id="" value="female" class="" vtype="vietor" />
            <span>Žena</span>
            <br />
            <br />
            <!-- Pohlavie -->
            <span>Dátum narodenia</span>
            <br />
            <input type="date" name="sex" id="" class="form_input_element_text" vtype="vietor" placeholder="DD/MM/RRRR" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <!-- Adresa -->
            <span>Adresa:</span>
            <br />
            <input type="text" name="adresa" id="" class="form_input_element_text" vtype="vietor"/>
            <br />
            <br />
            <button id="submit_button">Submit</button>
        </div>
```

And JS:

```
var myArray = [];
$( "input" ).each(function( index ) {

        if($(this).attr('type') == 'radio' && $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){
            name = $(this).attr('name');
            value = $(this).val();
        } else {
            name = $(this).attr('name');
            value = $(this).val();
        }

        myArray[name] = value;
    });

    console.log(myArray);
```

What I'm getting on console:

```
Datum narodenia: "2013-11-12"
adresa: "123 Road"
age: "19"
length: 0
name: "Jakub"
sex: "female"
surname: "Zak"
```

Even though the second radio button, of value = male, was checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at your `if` statement.

```
if($(this).attr('type') == 'radio' && $(this).attr('checked') == 'checked'){

} else {

}
```

The else then essentially means "if type not radio **OR** not checked".  So unchecked radio buttons will go into the else (which is the same as the `if`).  This means that when this code gets to the `female`, it will replace `male`.  I believe you wanted to ignore unchecked radio buttons, try this instead:

```
$( "input" ).each(function( index ) {

    if(this.type == 'radio' && !this.checked){
        return true;  // skip to the next iteration of the loop
    }

    /* Add to object */
});
```

Answer (score 1):

do you realize that both your if and else statements have the same codes?

```
 name = $(this).attr('name');
 value = $(this).val();
```

Same codes will generate same results, logically.

Comment: yes I did, it was just moment of weakness I had when I wrote that few lines, was just thinking about it completely wrong way. thank you though

Comment: @JakubZak no problem, would be glad if you give me +1 for it though.

Answer (score 0):

Your if and else cases do the same thing as each other. To get the value of all non-radio elements plus radios only if checked try this instead:

```
$( "input" ).each(function( index ) {
    if(this.type != 'radio' || this.checked)
       myArray[this.name] = this.value;
});
```

Note that you don't need to keep calling `$(this)` everywhere to retrieve the element value or type, you can access those properties directly from `this`.

Note also that you have another element with `name="sex"`, the `type="date"` input that appears after the radio buttons in your markup. So rather than `sex: "female"` in your console output I would expect the value of that date input to overwrite whatever you got from the radio buttons. You should rename that other input.

Demo: http://jsbin.com/OJAcaHE/1/edit

Finally, note that arrays are supposed to be used with numeric indices. If you want to have string keys you should be using an object, i.e.:

```
myObject = {}
...
myObject[someKey] = someValue;
```

Comment: All of these return same value of female, no matter which checkbox is checked

Comment: Sorry, yes, answer completely rewritten.